# iOS 20mb build limit

Tags: ios, build, app-store, limit

My final build is about 19.5mb, but it takes about 21mb size on the disk. 
So, will be my app limited for downloading from appstore in this case or not?

Sorry, if it's stupid question.

Comment: The limitation is for 3G download only. Via WiFi you can download apps of unlimited size.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm asking about - will be my app limitied for 3G if it's real size 19.5mb, but takes 21mb for storing in the file system on the mac (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new feature inside Xcode 4.3 that will estimate your app size, when it is posted to the appstore.

Just build an archive of your app in the usual way, and in the organizer it will tell you how large it is expected to be, as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the carrier, most carriers won't let you download over 20 GB on a 3G Network, but of course you can always download the app using WiFi

Answer (score 0):

I think it takes 21 MB (mega Bytes) and 19.5 Mb (mega bits). Since Snow Leopard Apple file system is computed into Bytes to avoid aving the impression of loosing space after formatting new hard drive (like you get 320GB drive and you get only 295Gb after formating)

Comment: 1 byte is 8 bits, so 21 MBytes = 168 Mbits. You are probably confusing the change where Snow Leopard started displaying sizes as true Megabytes instead of Mebibytes. i.e. 1 Megabyte = 1000 (10^6) Bytes, 1 Mebibyte = 1024 (2^20) Bytes.